# Передать значение выбранных checkbox в переменную js

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер. Пытаюсь доработать ajax-фильтр для wordpress. Столкнулся с проблемой получения массива из выбранных checkbox. Нашел в интернете код

```js
// Code goes here

jQuery(function($) {
  var $text = $('#text-input'),
      $box = $('.my-checkbox');
  
  $box.on('click change', function() {
    var values = [];
    
    $box.filter(':checked').each(function() {
      values.push(this.value);
    });
    
    $text.val(values.join(','));
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="text-input" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox" value="1" />
          First
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox" value="2" />
          Second
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox" value="3" />
          Third
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Но он выводит массив в input[type = "text"], а хотелось бы положить значения в переменную. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Последняя строка пишет в инпут значение, вот она `$text.val(values.join(','));`, попробуйте ее заменить например на `var checkedElements = values.join(',');`